# changing state of a child component (css properties)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, state

So I have an upload page Upload which has a child component Popup which is a pop up menu. The goal here is the click a submit button on the Upload page, and change the CSS properties of the Popup component to be able to make it visible. I am fairly new to ReactJS and I havent been able to find a question on here that gets me to where I need to be.

Here is the Upload Page component. Has the button with the submit() onClick:

```
class Upload extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            submitted: false,
        };
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    submit() {
      this.setState({
        submitWrapper: '500px',
        submitDetails: '300px',
        submitButton: 'block',
        opacity: '1',
        submitted: true
      });
      console.log(this.state)
    }



  render() {
    return(

          ....

           <button
            id="upload-submit"
            onClick={this.submit}>
            Submit
          </button>

           ....

           <Popup></Popup>
```

Here is the Popup Component. I am defining state here but I dont know how to change it from the parent component :(

```
class Popup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          submitWrapper: '0px',
          submitDetails: '0px',
          submitButton: 'none',
          opacity: '0'
        }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div id="submit-message"
           style={{height: `${this.state.submitWrapper}`}}>
          <h1 style={{opacity: `${this.state.opacity}`}}> GOOD JOB </h1>
          <hr style={{opacity: `${this.state.opacity}`}} />
            <div className="submit-details"
                 style={{height: `${this.state.submitDetails}`}}>
            </div>
            <button style={{display: `${this.state.submitButton}`}}
                    onClick={this.state.submitWrapper = '0px'}> Finished </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Popup;
```

I feel like I am missing something incredible easy here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While having a `Component-based` architecture, it's apparent to have your styles co-located with the component itself.

So instead of passing styles from the parent, styles are better managed using any `css-in-js` library, and then conditionally applying className.

So for your PopUp you'd have an `open` prop and set it from Parent. The Popup can then apply it's own styling based on the prop.

**Parent**

```
render(){
  return(){
     <PopUp open={this.state.open}/>
  }
}
```

**PopUp**

```
render(){
  return(){
    <div className={this.props.open ? 'popUpShow': 'popUpHide' }>
    </div>
  }
}
```

OR (with css-in-js lib )

```
render(){
  return(){
    <div className={this.props.open ? classes.popUpShow': classes.popUpHide }>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much ! Exactly what I needed! Makes a lot more sense to make classes anyways aha

Answer (score 0):

You want the submit function from your parent component to overwrite the state on your child component. You are passing `onClick={this.submit}>` as props to your button component but the `<Popup></Popup>` component does not receive this function. Add it:

```
<Popup onClick={this.submit}></Popup>
```

Also, on your child component this line `onClick={this.state.submitWrapper = '0px'}>` should be `onClick={this.props.onClick}` if you want the function on your parent component to overwrite the state on your child component.